# Issue using selenenium WebDriver to get text data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have successfully navigated to a websites page, that has multiple links to more pages. In my code I count the number of links, than convert it to xpath, so I can enter all the pages. It all works fine, until I try to get anything out of these pages. All of them have the exact form factor, so I should be able to use the same xpath inside the pages.
**
Here is the section of the code that fails:**

```
xpath_expression = '//*[@id="wrapper"]/main/section/div/div[2]/table/tbody'
element = browser.find_element("xpath", xpath_expression)
html_code = element.get_attribute("outerHTML")
number_of_pages_to_enter= html_code.count("<tr")
number_of_pages_to_enter=number_of_pages_to_enter-2
xpatht_eleje='//*[@id="wrapper"]/main/section/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['


cimek=''
for i in range(number_of_pages_to_enter):
    number_of_pages_to_enter_str=str(number_of_pages_to_enter)
    number_of_pages_to_enter_str=number_of_pages_to_enter_str+"]/td[3]/a"
    xpath_expression=xpatht_eleje+number_of_pages_to_enter_str
    button_locator = ("xpath", xpath_expression)
    button = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(button_locator)
    )
    button.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="eventHeader"]/div[2]/div/h1')
    cim=element.text
    cimek=cim+cim
    if number_of_pages_to_enter>0:
        number_of_pages_to_enter=number_of_pages_to_enter-1
    browser.back()
```

Here is the link of the page I am testing my code on:[text](https://www.tippmix.hu/sportfogadas#?q=nba&page=1)
The string called cimek, is where I try to collect the data.

I have already tried using other locators, then xpath, none works. The result that I get is only one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the issue is that you are looping through all rows using

```
for i in range(number_of_pages_to_enter):
```

but you aren't using `i`, you are using `number_of_pages_to_enter`.

---

Having said that, you are spending a lot of time/code parsing, calculating, building strings, etc. to loop through the table when there's a much simpler way. You just build a locator to the elements you want, use `find_elements(locator)`, and then loop through that group of elements.

Also, you are clicking the link to go to the next page to get who is playing in the game, e.g. "Cleveland - Dallas", but that info is already on the first page.

```
Kosárlabda, NBA
Cleveland - Dallas <<<
02.27. 18:00
```

I modified your code to get you this without having to click anything, leave the page and return, etc.

```
url = 'https://www.tippmix.hu/sportfogadas#?q=nba&page=1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
games = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr/td[3][@class='title']/a")))
for game in games:
    print(game.text.split("\n")[1])
```

Output

```
Cleveland - Dallas
Washington - Golden State
Orlando - Brooklyn       
New York - New Orleans   
Atlanta - Utah
Boston - Philadelphia
Milwaukee - Charlotte
Chicago - Detroit    
Minnesota - San Antonio
Oklahoma City - Houston
Portland - Miami
Hard - Bärnbach/Köflach
NBA 2023/24
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!(btw I want to go to each page, because I also want other information, the names of the teams is for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Selenium when there's a public api you could fetch the data from. Not sure what exactly you are after, but I dumped the json return into a table to show what you'd be getting on this request:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.tippmix.hu/tippmix/search'
payload = {
    "fieldValue":"nba",
    "sportId":0,
    "competitionGroupId":0,
    "competitionId":0,
    "competitionType":"",
    "type":0,
    "date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "hitsPerPage":9999,
    "page":1,
    "minOdds":"",
    "maxOdds":""}

jsonData = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()
```

**Output:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData,
                       record_path =['data','events'])
```

**Table: (just showing you first 3 rows here)**

```
print(df.head(3).to_string())
   eventId                 eventName matchStatus                  eventDate  eventVersion  bettingStatus  betradarId  sportId   sportName  competitionId competitionName  competitionGroupId competitionGroupName                                          competitions  isLive  isOutright  bettingPhase  hasVisiblePrematchMarket  remainingPrematchMarketCount  hasVisibleLiveMarket  remainingLiveMarketCount                                                                                                       eventParticipants                                                              competitionClosedCombinations eventClosedCombinations  liveStreamAvailable liveStreamEventId  liveStreamProviderId webNote  competitionGroupRefId  competitionRefId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    markets
0  3355538  Philadelphia - Charlotte              2024-03-02T01:00:00+01:00    1006964418              0    43066949        2  Kosárlabda           1296             NBA                 199                  USA  [{'type': 'competition', 'id': 1296, 'name': 'NBA'}]       0           0             0                      True                            68                 False                         0  [{'participantName': 'Philadelphia', 'participantId': 11869}, {'participantName': 'Charlotte', 'participantId': 2914}]  [{'cCGroupIds': [1], 'competitionId': 1299}, {'cCGroupIds': [1], 'competitionId': 42617}]                    None                False                                       0                             15               177  [{'marketId': 72774773, 'marketName': 'A mérkőzés győztese', 'marketType': 1, 'marketStatus': 1, 'channelWeb': 1, 'channelRetailer': 1, 'marketVersion': 1006954130, 'marketSubType': 2, 'minCombiCount': 1, 'minCombiCountLrt': 1, 'maxCombiCount': 2147483647, 'marketTypePriority': 2, 'marketTypeCCGroups': [1], 'mainMarket': 1, 'specialOddsValue': '', 'winnerOutcomeName': '', 'marketClosedCombinations': [], 'roundId': 0, 'outcomes': [{'outcomeNo': 1, 'outcomeName': 'Philadelphia', 'fixedOdds': 1.15, 'outcomeResult': 1, 'outcomeRealNo': '01'}, {'outcomeNo': 2, 'outcomeName': 'Charlotte', 'fixedOdds': 4.8, 'outcomeResult': 1, 'outcomeRealNo': '02'}], 'outcomeCount': 2, 'marketRealNo': '04525'}]
1  3355540       Detroit - Cleveland              2024-03-02T01:00:00+01:00    1006954126              0    43066947        2  Kosárlabda           1296             NBA                 199                  USA  [{'type': 'competition', 'id': 1296, 'name': 'NBA'}]       0           0             0                      True                            50                 False                         0        [{'participantName': 'Detroit', 'participantId': 3876}, {'participantName': 'Cleveland', 'participantId': 3113}]  [{'cCGroupIds': [1], 'competitionId': 1299}, {'cCGroupIds': [1], 'competitionId': 42617}]                    None                False                                       0                             15               177       [{'marketId': 72773000, 'marketName': 'A mérkőzés győztese', 'marketType': 1, 'marketStatus': 1, 'channelWeb': 1, 'channelRetailer': 1, 'marketVersion': 1006953998, 'marketSubType': 2, 'minCombiCount': 1, 'minCombiCountLrt': 1, 'maxCombiCount': 2147483647, 'marketTypePriority': 2, 'marketTypeCCGroups': [1], 'mainMarket': 1, 'specialOddsValue': '', 'winnerOutcomeName': '', 'marketClosedCombinations': [], 'roundId': 0, 'outcomes': [{'outcomeNo': 1, 'outcomeName': 'Detroit', 'fixedOdds': 3.9, 'outcomeResult': 1, 'outcomeRealNo': '01'}, {'outcomeNo': 2, 'outcomeName': 'Cleveland', 'fixedOdds': 1.22, 'outcomeResult': 1, 'outcomeRealNo': '02'}], 'outcomeCount': 2, 'marketRealNo': '04455'}]
2  3355482           Boston - Dallas              2024-03-02T01:30:00+01:00    1006954348              0    43066951        2  Kosárlabda           1296             NBA                 199                  USA  [{'type': 'competition', 'id': 1296, 'name': 'NBA'}]       0           0             0                      True                            57                 False                         0            [{'participantName': 'Boston', 'participantId': 2068}, {'participantName': 'Dallas', 'participantId': 3673}]  [{'cCGroupIds': [1], 'competitionId': 1299}, {'cCGroupIds': [1], 'competitionId': 42617}]                    None                False                                       0                             15               177          [{'marketId': 72773619, 'marketName': 'A mérkőzés győztese', 'marketType': 1, 'marketStatus': 1, 'channelWeb': 1, 'channelRetailer': 1, 'marketVersion': 1006954215, 'marketSubType': 2, 'minCombiCount': 1, 'minCombiCountLrt': 1, 'maxCombiCount': 2147483647, 'marketTypePriority': 2, 'marketTypeCCGroups': [1], 'mainMarket': 1, 'specialOddsValue': '', 'winnerOutcomeName': '', 'marketClosedCombinations': [], 'roundId': 0, 'outcomes': [{'outcomeNo': 1, 'outcomeName': 'Boston', 'fixedOdds': 1.22, 'outcomeResult': 1, 'outcomeRealNo': '01'}, {'outcomeNo': 2, 'outcomeName': 'Dallas', 'fixedOdds': 3.85, 'outcomeResult': 1, 'outcomeRealNo': '02'}], 'outcomeCount': 2, 'marketRealNo': '04572'}]
```